Display group aggregate and value in a column (with multiple Aggregated columns)
This is further to the Question and Answer in the below Post.
Display group aggregate and value in a column
How to Display if More than one column is aggregated. I have Invoice Value, Paid Value and Balance.
I wanted to have the Diplay like Invoice Number xxx (Invoice Value: xxxx Paid Value : xxxx Balance : xxxx)
